# The asymptotic behavior of $n\ln n -n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, asymptotics, factorial

How do I show that
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n\ln n - n}{\ln n!}=1?$$

Comment: $\ln n! \le \ln n^n = n\ln n$, and for any $\epsilon > 0$, for $n$ large, $\ln n! \ge \ln [(n(1-\epsilon))^{n(1-\epsilon)}] \ge n(1-\epsilon)^2 \ln(n)$.

Comment: Have you learned about integrals yet?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) you get
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\ln n - n}{\ln n!} &=
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1 + (n+1)\ln(n+1) - n\ln n}{\ln (n+1)}\\
& =
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(n+1) + n(\ln(n+1)-\ln n)}{\ln (n+1)} \\
&=
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(n+1) + \ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n}}{\ln (n+1)} \\
&=
1
\end{align}$$

You can also check some similar older questions (it seems natural that subtracting $n$ in the numerator does not change the limit):

- [Limit of $\frac{\log(n!)}{n\log(n)}$ as $n\to\infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/376988) ([one answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376988/limit-of-frac-lognn-logn-as-n-to-infty/377526#377526) is based on Stolz Cesaro)
- [How to calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log(x!)}{x\log(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3133887)
- [Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n!)}{n\ln(n)}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2484366)
- [Showing $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \log(n!)/(n\log n) = 1$ without using Stirling approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/181682) ([one answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181682/showing-lim-n-to-infty-logn-n-log-n-1-without-using-stirling-app/181705#181705) using Stolz Cesaro)

Answer (score 6):

don't need Stirling. For a function such as logarithm with $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) > 0,$  we get
$$  \int_{a-1}^b \; f(x) dx < \sum_{k=a}^b \; f(k) < \int_{a}^{b+1} \; f(x) dx $$

Here $f$ is log base e,  take $a=2$ and $b=n$
$$  \int_{1}^n \; \log x \; dx < \sum_{k=2}^n \; \log k < \int_{2}^{n+1} \; \log x \; dx $$

An antiderivative of $\log x$ is $x \log x  - x.$

$$ n \log n - n + 1 < \log n! < (n+1) \log (n+1) - n - 1 - 2 \log 2 + 2 $$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

By Stirling' formula,
$$\log n!\sim_\infty \log(2\pi n)+n\log n-n$$
so all you have to prove is that 
$$\frac{\log(2\pi n)}{n\log n-n}\to 0\quad\text{ as }\enspace n\to\infty.$$

Comment: It seems to me that this problem is equally difficult.

Comment: Just expand the numerator to log(2 Pi)+log(n) and then it all works out.

Answer (score 2):

As Bernard answered, the problem of the limit itself is quite simple using Stirling approximation of $\log(n!)$.

If you take one more term of this approximation, you could even get a quite good approximation since it will give
$$\dfrac{n\ln n - n}{\ln n!}\sim 1-\frac{\ln (2 \pi  n)}{2 n(\ln (n)-1)}$$ For example, using $n=100$, the exact value would be $0.991141$ while the approximation would give $0.991064$.